# Installing sshj or other java files

Tags: java, eclipse, sshj

How would you go about getting [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj) installed, considering that I'm using Eclipse on ubuntu? I haven't done anything with Java in 2 years and the only thing I sort of remember is how to add a jar file to a project, but in the case of sshj, I only have .java files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar is present in the zip distribution available on the [downloads page](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/downloads) for sshj.

Comment: Wow...not sure how I missed that